# How to improve my question?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-question

Some time ago I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22585729/1864610) about the GD library and transparency. Subsequently it's received a number of downvotes (which I suspect are retaliatory). I don't like downvotes, so mindful of advice to improve my question I took another look.

To my eyes the question appears to describe the problem I'm having, illustrates the results I'm getting and want, and includes my test piece code. I'd hate to think I run the risk of a question ban because of some minor point I've overlooked but I don't see how I can improve this, so I'd welcome suggestions.

Comment: So you got retaliatory downvotes and your response it to tell a bunch of people to spend time fixing up a question that doesn't actually have problems?  Seems counter productive, unless you're just begging for pity upvotes.

Comment: @servy No - actually this was a genuine request for some advice. I'd expect a better tone from someone with your rep.

Comment: I doubt someone with 13.5k is at risk for the question ban.  And your question doesn't have problems.  Not sure if downvotes were for content or comments removed, or some other obscure reason.

Comment: @MikeW But you knew that the question was fine.  Why genuinely ask for advice for a problem that you know that you don't have?  I'd expect someone with your rep to be more considerate of the time of users on the site instead of asking questions you already know the answer to.

Comment: @will - thanks for a more constructive reponse. If the question doesn't have problems I'll put the retaliatory votes down to the rubbish that pervades the site and move on.

Comment: Apparently you're not familiar with @Servy 's reputation...

Comment: The only thing you could do in that question is to remove this **"Ultimately I want to take a greyscale image convert the greyscale values to transparency values and overlay the result onto an image. That's for later."** Which isn't necessary to be there but it doesn't really have a major impact in your question.

Comment: Your question, IMHO, is just fine. In addition, the pic in the accepted answer is worth the downvotes! I can't even begin to understand why some downvotes get levied. There are apparently a number of folks on SO who are *impossible* to please.

Comment: Asked and answered.  You even accepted an answer.  Nothing more to see here.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils You know, I hadn't actually looked at that picture in any detail - I just checked over the code. Not a great choice, but thankfully, not mine.

Comment: @Servy Are you going to run for a mod position this time around?

Comment: @apaul34208 No, I have no reason to.  That's the beauty of SE; virtually all moderation actions can be done by non-moderators, and in particular most of the types of moderation actions I'd be interested in.  If I actually needed to be a mod to spend time moderating the site I'd have run years ago.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough... Martijn running made me think of a few of the other usual suspects here on meta that would be good for the job and your "reputation" put you on the short list.