# Figuring out how to improve a question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have asked this question
[Installing cminpack package in Msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122282/installing-cminpack-package-in-msys2) .
After a few days of not getting any feedback, I put a bounty on it. Almost instantly, I got it "put on hold as off-topic by ..."

Of course, I mean to abide by the rules of SE sites, to get a better whole system (in addition to getting an answer for this specific question).
There is clearly a range of obviousness on questions being off-topic or not.

So I visited the ["What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) topics of the help center, to try understanding the reason for the OP being off-topic.

I also [searched for other msys2 question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=msys2)...
(As an example, I found
[How are msys, msys2, and msysgit related to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019057/how-are-msys-msys2-and-msysgit-related-to-each-other)
and
[Differences between MSYS2 and Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751536/differences-between-msys2-and-cygwin) .
The latest one is "closed as too broad". I do not see it particularly broader than the first.)
I did not find many of the other questions in the search results significantly different than my OP in terms of being off-topic.

I also went [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260105/how-to-improve-my-question), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354784/how-to-improve-question-to-avoid-downvotes), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350028/how-to-figure-out-whats-wrong-with-a-closed-question), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=how%20to%20tell%20what%20is%20the%20reason%20for%20a%20question%20being%20off%20topic) (various other Meta question regarding topicality). 
I found no clue.

All in all, I mean to ask a question suitable for SO (or else?), but from what I saw, I am at a loss on how to improve it.

Comment: Note that you can @ mention the closer in a comment. The name will not show up in an autocomplete fashion, but they will be notified. I notified Yvette about this meta question using that functionality.

Comment: This questions seems like it'd be more suited on [unix.se]. Although I don't think it's *that* bad on SO itself - it's a question about using a programmer's tool and specifically installing it. Questions about dev tools (and installing them) are supposed to be on-topic.

Comment: Side note - I saw [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378140/why-was-a-question-about-installing-netbeans-closed-for-seeking-recommendations?rq=1) about installing NetBeans in the related list. It seems to be very similar in nature - installing a developer tool. The question itself was closed (which prompted the other meta question) and it now seems to be deleted. So, I'm not actually sure on the stance on *installing* tools any more.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Did not know that. Thanks.

Comment: @VLAZ - Since it is about Msys2, I guess it is off-topic on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).
And I shared your criterion: it's a question about using a programmer's tool; I would say it fits the description of SO.
One can find a few arguments in favor/disfavor on the topic of being off-topic... which side the scale tilts to is quite personal.
What I am confident is that there are quite a few questions, widely read on SO (no mention to "populraity/voting"), which were regarded on-topic, that are very similar to my OP in terms of "off-topicality".

Answer (score -1):

There was a mod flag on the post:

[image]

I removed the bounty and closed your post. I wasn't confident the question was a good fit for the site, so it's actually a favour to remove and refund the bounty. I believe by getting some help (hopefully on here) you can edit it into a more answerable question.

Say what you've tried.

Keep everything you can in the post, try not to link to other sites without including the pertinent parts from the link.

Comment: I think I already added all I tried which is relevant... will double check. Thanks.

Comment: are you happy with how this turned out @sancho.s?

Comment: I wouldn't say "happy". I guess it moved towards a more homogeneous criterion across SO questions... 
As said, for this OP (and I have seen it other times as well) criteria for "flagging", "off-topic"ing, etc. has a large disparity as compared to other OPs.
My guess: this is probably a signal that at least a minor change is required.
Maybe more specificity in the description of the SE sites (in particular SO), more flexibility in mods and users to change decisions (I found users are often overtly reluctant to saying "ok, good argument, decision revised") , etc.

Comment: Sometimes (but not this time) I see too much focus on reputation (from mods, and users flagging) and less on having a good SO...
Just a reflection.

Comment: @sancho.s I totally agree, which is why I asked for feedback. There's many brilliant programmers with zero rep on SO

Comment: But I fear I will not get answers... and I am certain the question is so simple that there should be tons of people out there knowing the answer.

Comment: @sancho.s unfortunately there's nothing we can do about that. Making the question the best quality you can and adding a bounty is all any of us can do. I understand I had a problem sort of like that too and it was painful, I'll get you a link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499092/error-msb3147-could-not-find-required-file-setup-bin-publish-to-local-failure I put a bounty on it and never got an answer. It was something I struggled with using Windows 10 which takes control of updates

Comment: Hmmm... yep, background noise.

Comment: Hey, cool to see my flag on Meta. @sancho.s I organically stumbled upon your Q and decided to flag it for the simple reason you asked 3 separate questions, which is the definition of Too Broad of a question. Also a seemingly trivial task of installing a feature is not the standard scope of SO.